# What is the PID on ps -ef | grep certb

Tags: process

I'm not technically sounded on ubuntu.

I'm trying to kill a process from terminal. I tried to find process ID using

`ps -ef | grep certb`

and killed as follows

`ps -ef | grep certb | awk '{print $2}'`

But it not seems working.
I have following response from ps -ef | grep certb

```
user  22354 10667  0 16:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto certb
```

I the above result which one is Process ID? **22354** OR **10667**?

Any help will  be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try look at the header in `ps -ef` output ... or read the manual page `man ps`. But the first number is the PID and the second is Parent-PID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose a process `certb` is currently running.

When you now run `ps -ef | grep certb` you get a list of processes 
that contain the text `certb` somewhere.

The moment you run the command, there will be **two** such processes:
the process `certb` itself ***and*** the process `grep certb`.

That's why you may already have seen the following instead:

```
ps -ef | grep certb | grep -v grep
```

This `grep -v grep` is to further filter out the `grep` command 
from the process list. There are other *tricks* to achieve the same 
result, but this is the most commonly used one.

As for your actual question: The output of `ps -ef` shows the PID of
the process in the 2nd column and the PID of the parent's process
(aka PPID) in the 3rd column.